# How to create combinatory variable in R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that has several variables with zero values. I need to construct an extra variable that would return the combination of variables that are not zero for each observation. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(firm = c("firm1", "firm2", "firm3", "firm4", "firm5"),
                 A = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
                 B = c(0, 1, 0, 42, 0),
                 C = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Now I would like to generate the new variable:

```
df$varCombination <- c("C", "B-C", NA, "A-B", "A")
```

I thought up something like this, which obviously did not work:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df$varCombination[i] <- paste(names(df[i,2:ncol(df) & > 0]), collapse = "-")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be probably solved easily using `apply(df, 1, fun)`, but here is an attempt to solve this column wise instead of row wise for performance sake (I once saw something similar done by @alexis_laz but can't find it right now)

```
## Create a logical matrix
tmp <- df[-1] != 0
## or tmp <- sapply(df[-1], `!=`, 0)

## Prealocate result 
res <- rep(NA, nrow(tmp))

## Run per column instead of per row
for(j in colnames(tmp)){
  res[tmp[, j]] <- paste(res[tmp[, j]], j, sep = "-")
}

## Remove the pre-allocated `NA` values from non-NA entries
gsub("NA-", "", res, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "C"   "B-C" NA    "A-B" "A"
```

---

Some benchmarks on a bigger data set

```
set.seed(123)
BigDF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 1e4, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))

library(microbenchmark)

MM <- function(df) {
  var_names <- names(df)[-1]
  res <- character(nrow(df))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    non_zero_names <- var_names[df[i, -1] > 0]
    res[i] <- paste(non_zero_names, collapse  = '-')
  }
  res
}

ZX <- function(df) {
  res <- 
    apply(df[,2:ncol(df)]>0, 1,
          function(i)paste(colnames(df[, 2:ncol(df)])[i], collapse = "-"))
  res[res == ""] <- NA
  res
}

DA <- function(df) {
  tmp <- df[-1] != 0
  res <- rep(NA, nrow(tmp))

  for(j in colnames(tmp)){
    res[tmp[, j]] <- paste(res[tmp[, j]], j, sep = "-")
  }
  gsub("NA-", "", res, fixed = TRUE)
}


microbenchmark(MM(BigDF), ZX(BigDF), DA(BigDF))
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
# MM(BigDF) 239.36704 248.737408 253.159460 252.177439 255.144048 289.340528   100   c
# ZX(BigDF)  35.83482  37.617473  38.295425  38.022897  38.357285  76.619853   100  b 
# DA(BigDF)   1.62682   1.662979   1.734723   1.735296   1.761695   2.725659   100 a
```

Answer (score 5):

Using apply:

```
# paste column names
df$varCombination <- 
  apply(df[,2:ncol(df)]>0, 1,
        function(i)paste(colnames(df[, 2:ncol(df)])[i], collapse = "-"))

# convert blank to NA
df$varCombination[df$varCombination == ""] <- NA

# result
df
#    firm A  B C varCombination
# 1 firm1 0  0 1              C
# 2 firm2 0  1 1            B-C
# 3 firm3 0  0 0           <NA>
# 4 firm4 1 42 0            A-B
# 5 firm5 2  0 0              A
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea but the logical comparison in your loop wasn't correct.

I've attempted to keep the code fairly similar to what you had before, this should work:

```
var_names <- names(df)[-1]

df$varCombination <- character(nrow(df))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){

  non_zero_names <- var_names[df[i, -1] > 0]

  df$varCombination[i] <- paste(non_zero_names, collapse  = '-')

}

> df
   firm A  B C varCombination
1 firm1 0  0 1              C
2 firm2 0  1 1            B-C
3 firm3 0  0 0               
4 firm4 1 42 0            A-B
5 firm5 2  0 0              A
```

Comment: Thanks! All the thus far suggested solutions work beautifully. So it is only matter of my taste to choose your version as the neatest. It lacks the NA replacement but that was not the stumbling block.

Comment: @Antti it's not only a matter of taste. Row wise operations are contr-intuative in R being a vecotirzed language and all. You've chosen the slowest solution by far. See some benchmarks in my answer. So please define "*neatest*" while you at it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I absolutely agree that row-wise looping in R is not a fast solution. In my defense, I do think the loop makes it a little clearer what's happening and I was trying to keep it close to the original code, so that the logic would be easier for the asker to follow.

Comment: I've also used a loop. Just column-wise instead of row-wise. And my loop was very simple to read. So using a loop isn't really an argument. Either way, I'm just saying that OPs comment doesn't make much sense to me. Though, I'm not trying to convince him to accept either answer neither. It's up to him to choose which answer he prefers and I don't really care if my answer being accepted or not.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think you got it right. The benchmarks you did convinced me. The time saving won't be trivial in my actual application. I'm just starting to realize the trade-offs in intuitiveness and efficiency. So I will after all accept your answer. Cheers!